# Reading and performing operations with Pipes

Tags: c, unix, process

I am supposed to read a matrix file, perform operations to the matricies read and output the results of those operations to a different file.

I am fairly new to pipes and I am able to do these oeprations with one process but we are required to run multiple processes. I understand I need to read the file in the parent and pass the necessary numbers to the children who perform the operations, but what's the general way to go about this?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Your title talks about pipes, then your first paragraph says "different file", then the 2nd paragraph talks about multiple processes ... It's hard to understand what you're trying to do. What "operations" do you need to perform?

Comment: Do you have to use pipes?  Shared memory seems like a more natural fit for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `fork()` (http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)

The use of `fork()` allows you to duplicate a process.

Try to explain better why you need to do it with multiple processes for more details.